# How to read very large files line by line matching patterns in R

Tags: r, bigdata, bioinformatics

I have a minimum of 10 GB size file that I need to read in R. To limit the memory use, I only want to read those lines matching patterns. For example, in the text file `mytext.tsv` below, I would like to read from wanted line which is going to be the header. Then read the lines that matches `coding` and `synonymous` from `col2`, i.e. `patterns`.

`patterns <- c("coding", "synonymous")`

mytext.tsv:

```
## lines unwanted
## lines unwanted1
## lines unwanted2
## lines unwanted3
wanted  col1       col2    
aaa     variant1   coding
jhjh    variant2   non-coding
ggg     variant3   synonymous
fgg     variant4   coding
gdg     variant6   missense
```

My expected dataframe should be:

```
wanted  col1       col2    
aaa     variant1   coding
ggg     variant3   synonymous
```

I know I can use connection and scan then loop over each pattern, but is there any efficient method to do this in R?

## Example of my actual data:

[image]

Comment: Eventually you can preprocess with awk, sed or PERL.

Comment: @jogo Yes, I thought about it, but was eager to know if it could be done within R.

Comment: I am guessing this is a VCF file? Maybe bcftools is more suitable?

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, it is an output of VEP.

Comment: Consider adding example of VCF file and "bioinformatics" tag, then you might get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *data.table* with *cmd* option and *grep* (not tested):

```
library(data.table)

fread(cmd = "grep 'coding\|synonymous' mytext.tsv",
      col.names = c("wanted", "col1", "col2"))
```

**Note:**

- This will work on *nix systems. On Windows there is a `findstr` command.
- Regex needs updating to fit with your data. This is just an example, and it will also return "non-coding" rows when grepping for "coding", etc.

Comment: @MAPK [read the manuals for grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), it accepts usual regex syntax. Or ask a new question with `regex` tag.

Comment: I just used without col.names and it worked: `df <- fread(cmd=paste("grep", patterns, "mytext.tsv"))`.